# Dealing with class imbalance in test set

Tags: data-science-model, data-wrangling

I am building a machine that tries to predict which ISP customers will complain due to issues with the network. I am having some difficulties.
The idea is to use network metrics of ~300K customers as predictors and score all customer on daily basis (likelihood of complaint for tomorrow based on todays network metrics).
The main challenge is that there are only between 100 to 400 complaints a day, so the predictive algorithm will have a very imbalanced set to work with, i.e. 300K total with ~300 positive!

I have tried to get around the problem by collecting positive cases over 6 months of complaints with choosing subset of random negative cases across 6 months (to reduce class imbalance). Then I have split this dataset on train/test (0.7 ratio), used train part of this dataset to train Gradient Boosting Machine and have obtained some good  results on the test set (Best outcome of 0.75 precision and 0.78 recall).

Following this, I test this trained machine on a random one day, with original ratio of 300K to ~300 positive cases. The trained algorithm performs exceedingly bad :-(
Is this the right approach or should I look at anomaly detection instead of classification?
Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: can you  elaborate more about what you mean by "all falls apart"?

Comment: also, in which dataset did you get 75 precision and 78 recall? the training or the test?

Comment: @alexmolas, Thanks for questions,I have edited my description. 
*The good result is on a test set, after I split my 6 month worth data set on train/test
* By "falls appart" I mean, the recall is close to 0 as well as extremely low precision. The accuracy is about 0.5 on this daily set

Comment: Is the "random one day" inside the training six months, or after it?  Was the training/test split done randomly, or based on time?

Comment: @Ben Reiniger , the one day test is done inside training time span of 6 months. The training/test was split randomly, irrespective of time.

Comment: Splitting time data without taking into account the time is an error and leads to data leaks. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117350/how-to-split-dataset-for-time-series-prediction

Comment: Testing on an original-balance dataset should produce comparable recall but worse precision, I think.  So I don't have an explanation for your terrible-recall result.  Could it just be a "hard" to predict day that was selected? Can you try again with another date?